# values should not empty when refresh and it should store the values in database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Here I am using drag and drop in jQuery.

I get the set of questions and set of answers from Database in array(article->question, article->answers), where answers be drag and dropped in the questions text box. On refresh the page the dragged values are comes to the original place not in that particular text box were I dropped.

Here My coding.

```
  <html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-  ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />  -->
 <style>
 /*#draggable { width: 50px; height: 20px; padding: 0.5em; } */
.drag_ans {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border: 0 none;
width: 100px;
}
#draggable {
width: 50px;
height: 20px;
background: white;
}
#droppable {
float: left;
margin: 50px;
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
 border: green;
}

   #ques {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
padding: 10px;
width: 100px;

  }
 </style>

   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#answer").click(function(){
 // alert('find a score');
    });
      });
  </script>
 </head>

<body>
<div class="container_inner">

<?php

 foreach($data as $article)
  {
   echo "<p>";
    echo "<b>";echo $article->article_name;
echo"</b>";
echo "</p>";
echo "<p>";
     echo $article->description;
  echo "</p>";
echo $article->video; echo "<br>";
    }
   ?>
  <?php
  $add=1;
foreach($question as $article)
     {
?>
    <!--    <div id="drop">  -->

   <p>
 <?php echo $article->question; ?>
 <input type ="text" id="ques_<?php echo $add; ?>" name="" class="ui-widget-content" />
  </p>
  <!--</div>  -->
<?php 
$add++;
    }
   ?>  



   <?php
      $counter=1;
    foreach($question as $article)
      {
?>
 <script>
      $(function() {

       $("#draggable_<?php echo $counter; ?>").draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });

     $("#ques_<?php echo $counter; ?>").droppable({

   drop: function( event, ui ) {

      $(this).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" ).find( "p" ).html( "Dropped!" );
      }
      });
       });
       </script> 
    <div id="draggable_<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="ui-widget-content drag_ans">
   <p>
    <?php echo $article->answer; ?>
    </div>
  </p>
 <?php 
$counter++;
  }
 ?>  

  <p> <input class="green_but" type="submit" name="NEW_SUBMIT" value="Submit" id="answer"/> </p>
  </div>
</body>
  </html>
```

Drag and Drop working fine and on refresh the page values all empty in the question text box.
   How to validate question and answer in jquery as this answer should store in DB after it dropped the question text box. And when clicking submit button, if answer to the question wrong the score should reduce. EX: If user answer set correct answer 4 out of 10 then the score should 4 out of 10.

Comment: show the code that receives the submitted form, also instead of making multiple scripts in your for loop, you could just use a selector like `$("div[id^='draggable_']").draggable` and `$("div[id^='ques_']").droppable`, not that this solves your problem but would be easier to debug one script instead of many.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what we are suppose to do...you say the answer in your post....the settings need to be saved. Obviously they are not getting saved so you have two methods to do so...

1) Submit a form and save the values there

2) Save the values via ajax attached to the one of the event handlers (probably the drop one : http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop)

My recommendation is not to do the whole drag and drop functionality while you are still learning the basics of web development.